# Regex (Pattern) para validar 3 numeros o letras descendentes o ascendentes (Javascript, Typescript, Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, regex

Necesito validar si una clave tiene mas de 3 caracteres seguidos con números o letras ascendentes o descendentes, solo se van a permitir hasta 3 caracteres seguidos. Solo necesito el regex o pattern.

Tengo este `(/[\d|\D]{4,}/g)` pero no me funciona.

Ejemplos:

> 58Pedrabcd -> INVALIDO
>   26An4321 -> INVALIDO
>   4abcd69 -> INVALIDO
>   4zyxw69 -> INVALIDO
>   1234Jose -> INVALIDO
>   58Pedr123 -> VALIDO
>   58Pedrxyz -> VALIDO
>   58Pedrzxy -> VALIDO
>   58Pedr321 -> VALIDO

Comment: Podrias mirar el [tour] para que sepas como funcionamos?? de paso, este 4zxyw69 por que razon es invalido?

Comment: zxyw es el abecedario en descendente, no puede ser ni ascendente ni en descendente con letras ni numeros.. osea ni abcd, dcba, wxyz, zyxw, 1234, 4321, 9876, 6789.. todo esto a partir de 4 caracteres

Comment: listo gracias... esperemos a ver si alguien me ayuda con esto

Comment: estas seguro que tiene que ser con una expresion regular? no me parece muy razonable

Comment: mas que seguro... así lo hice para todas las demás validaciones.. y como dije, tengo una ya aplicada pero no funciona correctamente, es una validacion con reactive forms en angular

Comment: De todas maneras, por lo que veo puedes usar una función como validador en reactive forms, asi que debes hacerlo por ese método en lugar de con un regex

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta corta es *No se puede hacer con regex*.

La respuesta larga es *La solución con regex es tan fea que nadie debería usarla*.Dicha solución es tener todas las opciones en la regex:

```
let re= /abcd|bcde|cdef| ... |wxyz|1234|2345| ... | 7890|zyxw|yxwv| ... |dcba|0987| ... |4321/gi;
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varias opciones, aunque utilizar expresiones regulares quizás sea la opción más *fea*.

**Opción 1 - expresión regular**

Es la misma idea que comentaba Pablo Lozano. Preparar todas las opciones inválidas y no permitirlas:

Utiliza esta expresión regular si la solución no es case sensive (ABCDe NO es válido, por ejemplo)

```
^(?!.*(?:0123|1234|2345|3210|3456|4321|4567|5432|5678|6543|6789|7654|8765|9876|abcd|bcde|cdef|dcba|defg|edcb|efgh|fedc|fghi|gfed|ghij|hgfe|hijk|ihgf|ijkl|jihg|jklm|kjih|klmn|lkji|lmno|mlkj|mnop|nmlk|nopq|onml|opqr|ponm|pqrs|qpon|qrst|rqpo|rstu|srqp|stuv|tsrq|tuvw|utsr|uvwx|vuts|vwxy|wvut|wxyz|xwvu|yxwv|zyxw)).+$
```

(recuerda a utilizar el flag 'i')

Demo [aquí](https://regex101.com/r/fGxUtu/3)

Si por el contrario ha de ser case sensitive (ABCDe es válido pero ABCDE no), utiliza esta otra:

```
^(?!.*(?:0123|1234|2345|3210|3456|4321|4567|5432|5678|6543|6789|7654|8765|9876|ABCD|BCDE|CDEF|DCBA|DEFG|EDCB|EFGH|FEDC|FGHI|GFED|GHIJ|HGFE|HIJK|IHGF|IJKL|JIHG|JKLM|KJIH|KLMN|LKJI|LMNO|MLKJ|MNOP|NMLK|NOPQ|ONML|OPQR|PONM|PQRS|QPON|QRST|RQPO|RSTU|SRQP|STUV|TSRQ|TUVW|UTSR|UVWX|VUTS|VWXY|WVUT|WXYZ|XWVU|YXWV|ZYXW|abcd|bcde|cdef|dcba|defg|edcb|efgh|fedc|fghi|gfed|ghij|hgfe|hijk|ihgf|ijkl|jihg|jklm|kjih|klmn|lkji|lmno|mlkj|mnop|nmlk|nopq|onml|opqr|ponm|pqrs|qpon|qrst|rqpo|rstu|srqp|stuv|tsrq|tuvw|utsr|uvwx|vuts|vwxy|wvut|wxyz|xwvu|yxwv|zyxw)).*$
```

Demo [aquí](https://regex101.com/r/fGxUtu/1)

**Opción 2: Expresión regular con un mínimo de código**

Aquí la idea es añadir a tu texto un texto adicional que servirá para simplificar la expresión regular. El texto adicional unirá todas las letras y símbolos de seguido con unos separadores.

Por ejemplo, pongamos que quieres validar un texto y pongamos que en ese texto el carácter arroba `@` no puede estar presente.

Tu texto pongamos que es: `58Pedrabc` (válido)

Entonces para validarlo le añadiremos al final lo siguiente:

`@@@0123456789@@@9876543210@@@abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@@@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ@@@zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba@@@ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA`

(todas las letras y números de seguido y también en orden descendente)

De forma que nos queda:

`58Pedrabc@@@0123456789@@@9876543210@@@abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@@@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ@@@zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba@@@ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA`

Ahora podemos validar con esta expresión regular:

`^(?!.*([^@\n]{4}).*\1)[^@\n]*`

Tienes una demo [aquí](https://regex101.com/r/DWzIsN/1)

Con javascript lo podrías hacer así:

```js
function validar_texto( texto ) {
  const diccionario = '@@@0123456789@@@9876543210@@@abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@@@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ@@@zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba@@@ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA';
  const texto_mas_diccionario = texto + diccionario;
  console.log(
    'El texto '
    + texto
    + ' '
    + (/^(?!.*([^@\n]{4}).*\1)[^@\n]*/.test(texto_mas_diccionario)
        ? 'sí' : 'no')
    + ' valida'
  );
}

validar_texto('foobar1234x');
validar_texto('foobar123x');
```

**Opción 3: Sin expresiones regulares**

Básicamente se trata de tener el listado de caracteres inválidos e ir recorriéndolos en grupos de 4 en 4. Para cada trozo, validaremos si se encuentra dentro del string de entrada.

Por ejemplo, con javascript:

```js
const invalidos = [
  '0123456789',
  '9876543210',
  'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
  'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
  'zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba',
  'ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA'
];

function validar_texto(texto) {
  const valido = invalidos.every(function(cadena) {
    return validar_texto_con_cadena(texto, cadena);
  });
  console.log(
    'El texto '
    + texto
    + ' '
    + (valido ? 'sí' : 'no')
    + ' valida'
  );
}

function validar_texto_con_cadena(texto, cadena, pos = 0) {
  if (pos > cadena.length - 4) return true;
  const trozo = cadena.substring(pos, pos+4);
  if (texto.indexOf(trozo) > -1) return false;
  return validar_texto_con_cadena(texto, cadena, pos+1);
}

validar_texto('foobar1234x');
validar_texto('foobar123x');
```

Answer (score 0):

Una solucion seria capturar los grupos de 3 letras o numeros, que es relativamente  facil con regex, y luego sobre ese string comprobar que si son ascendentes o descendentes con una funcion que los recorra y  `.charCodeAt()`